# Parsing string literals with FParsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I would like to parse string literals using FParsec. By "string literals" I mean something between opening and closing quote (in my case -- single quote):

```
'Please, switch off your mobile phone'
```

What I am currently doing is the following:

```
let string = between (pstring "'") (pstring "'") (manySatisfy isLetter)
```

But this stops after the first letter consumed. Is there any way to make it greedy?

Comment: The FParsec tutorial discusses how to parse string literals in http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-string-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's already greedy; `manySatisfy isLetter` parses a sequence of letters from the input stream.

The problem is that the parser fails with `,` or spaces since they are not letters. It could be fixed by using:

```
manyChars (noneOf "'")
```

or more explicitly using:

```
manySatisfy ((<>) '\'')
```

instead.

Comment: I believe that using string parsers like `manySatisfy` should be faster than the combination of `manyChars` and `satisfy`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that `manySatisfy` returns a `string`.